# How can I set the default value for a html <select> when the default value comes from database (it`s a page to edit an object) in blazor?

Tags: html, select

> Here I want to get a project from database to edit or change its properties for ex. destination country.
> when the project is loaded the select element should be already selected same as the project.DestinationCountry. Then I may change this property if needed.

```
<select type="text" class="form-control" id="Destination" value="@project.DestinationCountry">
       <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
       <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
       <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
</select>
```

> I tried to use value="@project.DestinationCountry" within select element but it did not work.

> Here is c# code

```
private ProjectModel project;
protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        project = _db.GetProject<ProjectModel>(id);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I did like this and it worked but I want to know if there is smarter solution for that.

```
<select type="text" class="form-control" id="Destination">
  <option value="">Select a country</option>
  @foreach (var country in Countries)
  {
     if (project.DestinationCountry != null)
     {
        <option value="@country" selected=@(project.DestinationCountry.ToLower() == 
        country.ToString().ToLower())>@country</option>
     }
     else
     {
        <option value="@country">@country</option>
     }
}
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't work since you can't add a value to the select element.

```
<select type="text" class="form-control" id="Destination" value="@project.DestinationCountry">
       <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
       <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
       <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
</select>
```

However, to make an option selected by default you need to use the `selected` attribute on `option`. To make sure the `select` element shows the fetched value from database, the best bet would be to use conditionals. If `project.DestinationCountry` matches the value add the `selected` attribute.

```
<select type="text" class="form-control" id="Destination">
   <option value="Canada" selected>Canada</option>
   <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
   <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
</select>
```

You can achieve this using conditional attributes

```
<select type="text" class="form-control" id="Destination">
    <option value="Canada" selected="@(project.DestinationCountry == "Canada")">Canada</option>
    <option value="Sweden" selected="@(project.DestinationCountry == "Sweden")">Sweden</option>
    <option value="Switzerland" selected="@(project.DestinationCountry == "Switzerland")">Switzerland</option>
</select>
```

This checks whether the condition matches. If `true` then the value assigned is same as the attribute name thus resulting in `selected="selected"`. When the value is `false` the attribute won't render at all. Or better use a for loop to output the options and for each entry you can check whether it's the current value and then add `selected` attribute to it to it.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I m beginner in .Net so may I ask you how and where I should have conditionals.

Comment: this works if I use foreach loop but not if I use like above (without foreach loop)

Comment: How about storing `project.DestinationCountry` in another variable and then reference the new variable's value?

Comment: Yes it works but I use foreach loop, it s better.

Comment: But now I have another problem :) . when the current project's destination country is null (because this property is nullable in database) I take this error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' so I should have conditional if project.DestinationCountry is null or not. but how ...